# detecting a character in input box

Tags: javascript

```
if(document.form.user.value=='')
```

this is  a javascript code which tests if it is empty input box,

but I need a piece of code which controls is there any character in input box?
could anyone help me?

I mean any character like  /, &, or any letter... or I can say any character which is not number!

Comment: Are you looking for some specific character? Or maybe you want to ignore spaces? Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Add the negation `!` operator to your `if` statement:</strike>

```
if (!document.form.user.value=='')
```

Will return true if the value is different than an empty string (that is, if it has any character).

Or simply add an `else` block to your current `if`..

```
if(document.form.user.value=='') {
    //empty value
} else {
    //not empty
}
```

**Updated answer as per question/comment update:**

Use a regex to match for non-number characters:

```
if (/[^\d]/.test(document.form.user.value))
    //contains a non 0-9 character
```

[`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) is another viable option, but it'd allow for some non 0-9 characters: float `.` and negative `-` values would be allowed.

Comment: I meant any /, &, or any letter...  or I can say any character which is not number!

Answer (score 1):

You mean if there is one or more characters, i.e. not empty?

```
if (document.form.user.value != '')
```

or:

```
if (document.form.user.value.length > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check is value exist:

```
if($(input).val())
```

Or:

```
if($(input).val().length > 0)
```

Comment: the question is more generic, not jQuery or any other library specific.