# how to detect if a #hash tag is being entered in and input element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, regex

My question is simple:

How do I make the use of JavaScript `regex` to detect whether a `#hashtag` is being entered in the input element? I have a function to convert the hashtag into a clickable link but it's PHP. I want a similar function but in jQuery the reason is that if a hashtag is entered then I can send a value to the PHP processor form.

Sorry there is no code as I dont know much about JavaScript `regex`, also, I could not find any good tutorials.

Comment: Your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004197/detecting-a-character-in-input-box

Comment: Or  try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181066/detect-if-special-characters-entered-in-input-element-js

Comment: Are you looking for a regex like this? http://regex101.com/r/vH9uQ3

Comment: Are you trying to check for just the hash character `#` or hash tags like `#foobar`?

Comment: @SimpleJ #foobar if this hash tag is entered a value is sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for this: `(#\w*)`

```
function hasNonStandard(inputElem) { 
    return /[#\w*]/.test(inputElem.value);
}
```

Comment: you might want to make that a global search in case they enter more than one.

Comment: Do you mean like: (\w*#\w*)?